# PHP MySQL Update query array(0) { }

Tags: php, mysql

Can anybody help me to understand why my query update dosen't update my data in my database.

This my code php :

```
<?php

$code = $_GET['code'];
$n1= $_GET['n1'];
$n2= $_GET['n2'];
$n3 = $_GET['n3'];

try {
  $connexion= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data','mydata','password');
  $sql_update = "UPDATE data.check SET  numb_1='".$n1."',numb_2='".$n2."','numb_3'='".n3."' WHERE 'code_product' =".$code;
  $query = $connexion-> prepare($sql_update);
  $query -> execute();
  $data_update= $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

catch(PDOException $e)
{
 echo "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Because `update` queries don't return any data.

Comment: you are using update.you should use select to return any data

Comment: Also think about what happens if I send `...&code=0%20or%201=1` in the GET request. This code is wide open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I think you got enough time to go through the answer given below. Atleast respond to the answer @ZouZou.

Comment: @NanaPartykar I just tested your code.

Comment: So What Happened @zouzou?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Change

```
$sql_update = "UPDATE data.check SET  numb_1='" . $n1 . "',numb_2='" . $n2 . "','numb_3'='" . n3 . "' WHERE 'code_product' =" . $code;
```

To

```
$sql_update = "UPDATE data.check SET  numb_1='" . $n1 . "',numb_2='" . $n2 . "','numb_3'='" . $n3 . "' WHERE `code_product` =" . $code;
```

=> In `n3` you forgot to add `$`. And, replace single quotes with backtick to enclose column name.

**Updated Code**

```
<?php

$code = $_GET['code'];
$n1 = $_GET['n1'];
$n2 = $_GET['n2'];
$n3 = $_GET['n3'];

try {

  $connexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data', 'mydata', 'password');

  $sql_update = $connexion->prepare("UPDATE `data`.`check` SET numb_1 = :numb_1 , numb_2 = :numb_2, numb_3 = :numb_3 WHERE `code_product` = :code_product");
  $sql_update->execute(array(':numb_1' => $n1,':numb_2'=>$n2, ':numb_3'=>$n3,':code_product'=>$code));


  $stmt = $connexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM `data`.`check` WHERE code_product=:code_product");
  $stmt->execute(array(':code_product'=>$code));
  $data_update= $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have mysqli and pdo?

Comment: My Bad @Ivan . Thanks For Pointing Out.

Comment: I have a problem PDO not throwing exception with unbound parameters

Comment: Why you want to throw exception? Code is working or not? Data coming or not @zouzou.?

Comment: @NanaPartykar data is not coming :(

Comment: One silly mistake was there @zouzou. See my update code section and again use it. What i did is I replaced ``data`.`check`` with ``data.check``

Comment: @NanaPartykar Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good. Glad It Worked. @zouzou. *Keep Coding*

Answer (score 1):

After your `update` execution you need to query again for fetching result like,

```
$sql_update = "UPDATE data.check SET  numb_1='".$n1."',numb_2='".$n2."','numb_3'='".$n3."' WHERE 'code_product' =".$code;
$query = $connexion-> prepare($sql_update);
$query -> execute();

$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM data.check");
$query->execute();
$data_update= $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);// now it will get records
```

Comment: Why not just have one query with two statements (UPDATE and SELECT)?